# Let thread wait for dialog input

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service, wait

I have programmed a structure that works like this:

```
Activity discoveryActivity - UI thread
 ↕ Calls through interface
Service discoveryService   - Bound service running on UI thread
 ↕ Actions through Handler.post(↑) or functions (↓)
Runnable connectionThread  - Socket networking
```

At some point the `connectionThread` needs a `String` to continue.

1. So I make a call with `Handler.post(..)` to the `discoveryService` which
2. notifies the `discoveryActivity` to show an `AlertDialog`

The user needs about 20 seconds to input the data and will confirm the input.

**Problem 1:** *What will the thread do in the meantime?*

Now I need to make my way down to the Thread again.

Getting to `discoveryService` is easy

**Problem 2:** *How can I get the thread working again without restarting? The thread is in a complex loop with a few `Socket`s right now!*

My first idea was to keep the thread running

```
// Inside run()
while(stringWrapper.get() == null) {
    Thread.sleep(500);
}

// Outside run()
void setStr(String s) { stringWrapper.set(s); }
```

But that is inefficient

Then I read about `wait()` and `notify()`
I tried that on the thread itself and on the `StringWrapper` (A simple class that holds a reference to a `String`)

I am helpless right know and I think `wait()` and `notify()` are the right way to go?

Can you give me a hint where I should implement these and on which object they would be called?

**TL;DR:** I want to let a thread pause until it receives data

Comment: Are you using a custom networking protocol that libraries such as OKHttp or Java's URLConnection can't handle? It seems that you coding at a very low level for an app.

Comment: I don't use any libraries except BouncyCastle which i need for `BKS` support. The protocol I developed works with states and I modified the SSL handshake a little bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you're trying to accomplish, but you may be able to use a `SettableFuture` (from [Google Guava library](https://github.com/google/guava)) to solve your issue.

```
private final SettableFuture<String> stringFuture = SettableFuture.create();

// Inside run()
// This will block your thread until stringFuture is set, or until the given timeout has expired.
final String string = stringFuture.get(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

// Outside run()
public void setStr(final String s) {
    stringFuture.set(s);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I am trying to accomplish! I will edit my question to make it more clear.